# Cisco 2960X is 'normal' IOS CLI or not?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

I asked a previous question "Low end cisco switch with 'regular' CLI - which led me to look at the 2960X platform as an affordable access layer switch at a branch office.. I know on the older 2950's managing them was the same as managing any other standard device via CLI..

The 2960 platforms list 'simplified management' .. which scares me.  Anyone using these now can verify it's just regular cat IOS, using all standard commands etc, just with a reduced set of features?

If it uses a fruity SMB type CLI I want to avoid this platform.

Comment: The question has been answered, but I wanted to point out that newer switches don't run CatOS. CatOS is the software that older Cisco switches used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Cisco 2960-X is an IOS platform. According the to the datasheet it ships with LAN Lite, LAN Base, or IP Lite(*all IOS variants*) depending on the hardware you select. You may want to consult the documents linked below to determine what feature(s) you require, as the lite models cannot be upgraded to the comparable base IOS version.

[image: 2960 LAN-LITE]

[2960-X Data Sheet](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps12995/data_sheet_c78-728232.html)

[2960 Q&A](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps6406/prod_qas0900aecd80322c37.html)

Comment: I get that, I was asking for management, am I going to see a difference in the WAY I manage these devices when I'm at the CLI vs. the normal IOS CLI (like say... on a 3750).  The phrase 'simplified management' made me worry it was some kind of different CLI like the small business products use, in which case I don't want to purchase this product.

Comment: The switch variants run IOS, therefore, other than features that have been stripped from the lite and base versions, compared to lets say *IP Services*, the CLI management is still IOS. These switches do not run the SMB CLI.

Comment: Awesome, ty this is what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

The 2960X utilises a similar IOS as previous 2960 switches in terms of commands. The only differences come from the different IOS images - this depends on the feature sets and how much you pay. You will also find that you can add more than 1 SVI on the newest series too. (Up to 3 depending on the feature set of your IOS image (which can be nifty for a management vlan)

As for your fears, no, the newer series of 2960X is not running the same OS as the equivalent Linksys small business switch line CLI.

Here are some common questions and answers re: the new 2960X series.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps12995/qa_c67-728348.html